# Need to get the column from the table in exists clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query below:

```
SELECT AIDI.LOAN_NUM, AIDI.LOCATION_CODE, AIDI.ORD_NUM, AIDI.MTN, AIDI.LOAN_STATUS, COUNT(*)
    FROM table1 AIDI
    WHERE AIDI.LOAN_STATUS = 'A'
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ORDERS AO
        WHERE AO.ACE_ORD_NUM = AIDI.ORD_NUM
        AND AO.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE -1)
        AND AO.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME < TRUNC(SYSDATE))
    GROUP BY AIDI.LOAN_NUM, AIDI.LOCATION_CODE, AIDI.ORD_NUM,         AIDI.MTN, AIDI.LOAN_STATUS
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I need to get the AO.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME this column into select clause so that i can see the date also in the result set.

Comment: If there are multiple matches, which one do you want?

Comment: the ones that has staus 'A' between yesterday and today

Comment: @kanak you didnt get Gordon's point. You just ask the db to see if something `EXISTS`.. And DB can only say Yes or No (True or false), not bring you those details, because there may be more than one match.. If you want the values, use a join..

Comment: Oh okay, I am fine now...used left outer join for this one and got the result.